# Why does my program look for Commons.dll instead of Commons.lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

In the project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies I guided the compiler to look for `Commons.lib`.

Moreover, 
at VC++ directories -> Library Directories I added `$(SolutionDir)\Debug`, where `Commons.lib` is to be found.

Yet, for some reason when running the project it's trying to look for `Commons.dll` and failing.

Why?

Here's the message:

> The program can't start because Commons.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some libraries are so-called *export libraries*, which only contains stubs for the function in a DLL. To be able to use the library the DLL must be loaded.

The library is used by the linker as part of the build-process, and the DLL is loaded by Windows (or equivalent) when your program is loaded to be executed.

Comment: My intention is to be able to load it statically. `Commons` is another project of mine (not some external library) so what should be changed?

Comment: @Covvar And you built this "Commons" library *as* a static library and not a DLL? How did you create your project?

Comment: By the way, at some point I was able doing it but something must have been changed along the way..

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the `Debug` dir

Comment: @Covvar *What* can you see in the `Debug` dir? A DLL project usually creates an export library. Do you see a `Commons.dll` too?

Comment: Commons.dll/pdb/log. That's it.

Comment: @Covvar Well there you have it. There's the DLL you need. Copy it to the same directory as the executable and it should work.